# Can multiple instances of procedure create same #Temp simultaneously?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, tempdb, temporary-tables

I have a procedure which inserts data into #temp table.
After performing certain manipulations to the data, it stores data from #temp table to some other table.

I cannot run multiple instances of this procedure simultaneously. Why?
We create #temp table with the same name in multiple tabs. Then why shouldn't we be able to do the same for multiple instances of temp table?

Any solutions?

Example:

```
--exec dbo.testing_temp_table
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testing_temp_table]
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_1') IS NOT NULL drop table #temp_1
    select  * into #temp_1 from dbo.Emp

END
```

Comment: does the `#` symbol magically cause a temp table? or are you just creating a public table? (I'm not familliar with ms sql)

Comment: @Jasen Yes, it does create a temp table. There are local and global ones too. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#temporary-tables).

Answer (score 8):

> "I cannot run multiple instance of this procedure simultaneously. Why?"

Could you clarify what you mean by "cannot run"? Do you get an error?

Now, you don't need to check the existence of the table in your stored procedure with the IF OBJECT_ID() thing.

SQL Server will create an instance of the temp table per instance of the stored procedure, and it will only be visible to the creating scope, which is the stored procedure in this case, and to inner scopes, such as if you call another sub-procedure in your code. Once the procedure completes, the temporary table will be gone.

Under the covers, the query processor appends some unique string to the table name in TempDB for each instance.

BOL has all the details: [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

-- **In response to OP comment regarding the stored procedure generating the same suffix.** --

You are not giving SQL Server enough credit here. If your claim was true, this would have been a major bug; executing multiple instances of a stored procedure which use temp tables is completely supported.

I suspect that you are testing it on a single connection, and seeing that upon re-execution of the same proc, you get the same suffix. This is an optimization for reusing the suffixes for repeated executions from the same session.

What you should test is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P 
AS
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #T(Col1 INT);
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
SELECT * FROM TempDB.sys.tables;
END
```

And then on two or more connection, execute concurrently

```
EXEC P
```

Here is what comes up for me:

| name |
| --- |
| #T_____________000000000004 |
| #T_____________000000000005 |

HTH

Comment: same question but for postgre.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is scope.  @SQLRaptor is completely correct in his response above but it might help if you look at it like this:

If you create a temp table it is scoped to your session.  In other words it will exist until your session is closed or you or drop it.  What you are expecting is for your temp table to be scoped to your stored procedure (which isn't the case) like a table variable would be.  Example:

```
-- Query window (otherwise known as session in this case)
Create #temp1 (temp table)
Create @temp1 (table variable)
     -- Run a stored procedure
     Create #temp2 (temp table)
     Create @temp2 (table variable)
     -- Currently all four exist.
-- On leaving the stored procedure the following exist:
-- #temp1
-- #temp2
-- @temp1
    -- Rerun the same stored procedure
    You attempt to create #temp2 but it fails because #temp2 still exists.
```

Now if you leave the session (query window) entirely then all of them go away.

There are also global temp tables.  The ones with ## at the beginning.  These are scoped to all sessions and will only go away when no one is using them anymore.

Basically, unless you plan on re-using  your temp table for some reason drop it at the end of your SP.  So like this:

```
--exec dbo.testing_temp_table
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[testing_temp_table]
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select  * into #temp_1 from dbo.Emp

    -- The rest of your code goes here

    DROP TABLE #temp_1
END
```